# Javascript Or Jquery find html array length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following html

```
<input name="altLocation[1][name]">
<input name="altLocation[1][location]">
<br>
<input name="altLocation[2][name]">
<input name="altLocation[2][location]">
<br>
<input name="altLocation[3][name]">
<input name="altLocation[3][location]">
```

Is there a way to find the length of `altLocation` using JS or jQ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `altLocation.length`?  Otherwise, I have absolutely no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Comment: To answer your question: Yes

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name^=altLocation]").length; // `NodeList`
```

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[name^=altLocation]")).length; // `Array`
```

Comment: Why convert it to an array just to get the length? By definition, any array-like object has a `.length` property?

Comment: @Barmar To address specific text at Question. OP mentions "array". Not only to get `.length`.

Comment: I think the array he's asking about is the inputs with array-style names, he's not really asking about a Javascript array.

Comment: He said "html array length", not "Javascript array length".

Comment: @Barmar Could be viewed either way. Should not be an issue providing both options, depending on what ultimate expected result is.

Comment: @Barmar `Array.from()` would be option where OP appears to be trying to determine number of elements having distinct attributes, perhaps along with getting or setting for each element; possibly returning an array of values. Though not clear that this is case from OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `length` of any jQuery selector to tell you how many it has found.

jQuery also allows full css selectors, including `^=` 'starts with'.

You can combine the 2 to get the following.

Not sure if you wanted 6 or 3 as an answer. Just remove the `/ 2` if you wanted 6 not 3.

```js
console.log($('input[name^=altLocation]').length / 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="altLocation[1][name]">
<input name="altLocation[1][location]">
<br>
<input name="altLocation[2][name]">
<input name="altLocation[2][location]">
<br>
<input name="altLocation[3][name]">
<input name="altLocation[3][location]">
```

Comment: And if the input's name is `altLocationWrong[1][name]`?

Comment: call it something else like `wrong_altLocation` so its ignored by the above. or do a further jQuery filter to exclude those you don't want. i think you can use something like `not(input[name*=altLocationWrong]` to exclude the above

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming that each "element" of `altLocation` has a `name` "property":

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++) 
  if (x[i].name && /^altLocation\[.*\[name\]$/.test(x[i].name))
    total++;

alert('Length is: '+ total);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u18uz4r8/1/)

Comment: The first `indexOf()` test should be `=== 0`, so you don't get fooled by `name="anotheraltLocation[1][name]"`

Comment: You should replace `.*` to `\d+\]`

Comment: @klenium Although it is a possible assumption, I'm not sure the index will always be a number. Good comment however.